# QueryString containing \ coming through with \\

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm have a page which I sent a parameter through the query string.

If I'm retrieving it with Request.QueryString["Format"] I'm having troubles with the type 'CD\DVD'. It's being returned as 'CD\\DVD'. It's important I get this as the right string.

How do I avoid the extra backslash? Or even get rid of it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Urlencoding and decoding your querystring

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: That sounds like a good approach Ives. However it is for a module for a CMS. I will be relying on administrators adding links to encode their links as I understand it? It wouldn't be via for this?

Comment: I agree 100% with you. It would be a big pain to maintain this. The easy solutions are to replace \\ by \ or not use \ on the querystring to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
Request.QueryString["Format"].Replace(@"\\",@"\");
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work however I think it should be @"\" to compile

Comment: Just tried it you need @"\\" as well or "\\" will be treated as '\'

Comment: ah, my bad. I'm not very familiar with c#

Comment: No worries, what you gave was helpful and put me on the right track.